# Manually specifying include directory for Swift C module

Tags: c, swift, macos

I have a C library `MyLib` that I am trying to use in a Swift app. I want to use a local copy of the library, so I don't want to install it or add my bridge header to its files. I clone the library to `Sources/ClibMyLib/MyLib` so the package structure looks like this:

```
App
  | Package.swift
  | Sources/
    | ClibMyLib/
      | module.modulemap
      | bridge.h
      | MyLib/
        | include/
          | myLibHeader.h
        | source/
          | *.c
```

I specify `bridge.h` as the header in the module map:

```
module ClibMyLib {
    umbrella header "bridge.h"
    link "MyLib"
    export *
}
```

The problem is that the `include` directory of `MyLib` is not visible to `bridge.h` So if `bridge.h` looks like this:

```
#include "myLibHeader.h"
```

it fails to build since it can't find `myLibHeader.h`. If I specify the path from `bridge.h` to the local copy like this:

```
#include "MyLib/include/myLibHeader.h"
```

then any transitive includes in `myLibHeader.h` still fail.

This would be very easy to solve in a C build, I would just add `MyLib/include` as an include directory. I haven't been able to find a way to do something similar in Swift - most guides I have found install the library and include from `/usr/local/include/`.

Are my only options to place `bridge.h` in the library's include directory or to install the headers to `/usr/local/include`? Adding `bridge.h` to the library is not ideal, the include directory file structure is more complicated than the simple example I gave. I just want to be able to manually specify an include directory.